# Could not find package "flutter_native_splash". Did you forget to add a dependency?

Tags: flutter, yaml

I'm using the [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) package. How do I fix this error?

Pubspec.yaml -

```
  cupertino_icons:

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter_native_splash:
 image: assets/splash.png
 color: “6a1b9a”
 android: true
 fill: true

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
```

Error:

```
PS C:\Users\project> flutter pub pub run flutter_native_splash: create
Could not find package "flutter_native_splash". Did you forget to add a dependency?
```

Comment: It should no indent front of 'flutter_native_splash'

Comment: if you are still looking for a solution then check out my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the dependency in dev_dependencies not dependencies

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_native_splash: ^0.1.9 //Add this here
```

Comment: Even ensuring this doesn't helps. The entry for flutter_native_splash is in pubspec.lock as well

Comment: flutter pub pub run flutter_native_splash:create

Answer (score 4):

This is a very silly issue. Even I encountered this today. Maybe we were referring same tutorial from where we took the commands. The problem is with the space just before create, proper command is `flutter pub pub run flutter_native_splash:create`

Got the solution from [here](https://github.com/henriquearthur/flutter_native_splash/issues/81)

Comment: Oh yes the same about me. 40 mins of my live are saved by you)

Answer (score 1):

Add pub under dev_depences: in your pub.yaml file

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_native_splash: ^1.2.1
```

Add file to project root folder where pub.yaml is:
Run `flutter_native_splash.yaml`
Run `flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create --path=flutter_native_splash.yaml`

Answer (score 1):

The correct command: **flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create**

You just need to add *flutter_native_splash* in dev_dependencies too.

and later as define "flutter_native_splash:" after it.

Refer to the image:
[PUBSPEC.YAML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEfmK.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Check the indentation when you add the package, .yaml needs indentation to nest the package under the dependency

Answer (score 0):

Remember to ***save the file*** before using **flutter pub get**, then use

> dart run flutter_native_splash:create